# Why am I getting an "undefined" error when returning a string with a callback in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular 11 and Typescript and I'm getting an error that I don't understand. I've got a callback function in a service that seems to successfully return a string. I want to add that to another string that's declared in my class but I get the following error: *TypeError: Cannot set property 'test' of undefined*. I know that I'm probably doing the callback wrong but why does it successfully write the response to console but not to the variable "test"?

Here is my class:

```
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit  {
    test: string;

    constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testService.test(function(response: string) {
            console.log(response); //this bit is fine
            this.test = response; //this returns an error
        });
    }
}
```

And in my service:

```
test(callback) {
    callback("foo");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arrow function like this.

```
 test: string | undefined ;

 constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {

 this.testService.test((response: string) => {
 this.test = response;  });
 }
```

Or else you can do this using RXJS as follows

service class

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

test(): Observable<any> { return of('foo') }
```

component class

```
 test: string | undefined ;

 ngOnInit(): void {this.stackService.test().subscribe(res => this.test = res);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow functions :

```
this.testService.test((response: string) =>  {
    console.log(response); //this bit is fine
    this.test = response; //this returns an error
});
```

Although I would say that this method of callback is a little strange. Because you are using Angular, it's much more common to use RxJS to subscribe to observables and handle the callback yourself.